# System.Timers.Timer Elapsed event fired more than once time in Windows Service

Tags: c#-4.0, timer, windows-services

I'm working on a Windows Service with a timer to schedule a job each interval of time.
It seems that the timer elapsed event is fired more than one time.

Here a code sample:

```
private static System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
      _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
      _timer.Interval = 1000;
      _timer.Enabled = true;
      _timer.Start();
}

private void OnTimedEvent(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
      _timer.Enabled = false;
      _timer.Stop();

      //Do the job

      _timer.Enabled = true;
      _timer.Start();
}
```

Can you help me?
Thank you

Comment: You don't need to call both Enabled and Start - From MSDN: `Start() - Starts raising the Elapsed event *by setting Enabled to true.* `

Comment: It is a bug in your code.  Start the service more than once and you'll add yet another event handler to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The signal to raise the Elapsed event is always queued for execution
>   on a ThreadPool thread, so the event-handling method might run on one
>   thread at the same time that a call to the Stop method runs on another
>   thread. This might result in the Elapsed event being raised after the
>   Stop method is called. The code example in the next section shows one
>   way to work around this race condition.

Quoted from: [Timer.Stop Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.stop.aspx). Please see the code sample on the page.

Comment: Thanks, I understood. I set Timer.AutoReset property to false and removed Timer.Stop() and now works fine.